# TRYING TO UPDATE AN DataSet WITH DataAdapter

Tags: vb.net

WEll i am here again asking for your help, i am working on an update of my Windows Application, when i wrote i use SQL 2005 and VS.Net 2005 but now i am using VS.Net 2008 and SQL 2008, my problem is when i want to execute an update of a DataSet, i am using DataAdapter and a SqlCommandBuilder...i am looking for an explanation why i get this error:

"NellReferenceExeption Was Unhandled" it suppose i have to use the word "new" but where??? in my VS.Net 2005 doesn't have this problem but now in my VS.Net 2008 i get this unconfortable error....let me describe you my application:
When the form load it populate an DataGridView from my DataBase and it is no problem but when i do "click" on my button to update my DataBase with the changes made on my DataGridView i sadly found the error, above my code in the event "click"

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    If ConsejeraSet.HasChanges Then
        Dim filas As Integer, i As Integer
        filas = ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejera").Rows.Count ----**This line shoot the error**------
        For i = 0 To filas - 1
            If ConsejeraSet.Tables("ConsejeraSet").Rows(i).RowState = DataRowState.Added Or ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejeras").Rows(i).RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then
                If IsDBNull(ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejeras").Rows(i).Item("Codigo_Consejera")) Or IsDBNull(ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejeras").Rows(i).Item("Nombre")) Or IsDBNull(ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejeras").Rows(i).Item("Apellidos")) Or IsDBNull(ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejeras").Rows(i).Item("Equipo")) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor llenar los 4 campos que son necesarios", "IMPORTANTE")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Try
            Form2.conexionLocal = New SqlConnection(Form2.miCadena)
            Form2.conexionLocal.Open()
            Me.consejerAdapter.Update(ConsejeraSet, "Consejeras")
            MessageBox.Show("Tabla Consejeras actualizada con éxito")
        Catch ex As DuplicateNameException
            MessageBox.Show("No se puede Actualizar pues esta duplicado un codigo")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Form2.conexionLocal.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No han habido cambios")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the try/catch and the IDE will show you what is Nothing and where.  You should also explore explicit form references.  Meanwhile please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks i found my error i was rote some line of trash maybe i was asleep when it done but well i will read how to ask and i was reading your tips about NRE, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am sorry i read slowly my code lines and found my error was this:

```
filas = ConsejeraSet.Tables("Consejera").Rows.Count*****
```

in this line i am searching for a table called "Consejera" but in sql my table called "Consejeras" so if i solve this other line shoot me the same error and was the same, i was wrote trash code lines....

```
If ConsejeraSet.Tables("ConsejeraSet").Rows(i).RowState = DataRowState.Added Or......
```

in this line i am calling the same table "Consejeras" and i wrongly wrote "ConsejeraSet" the name of my DataSet.....i am really sorry and i thanks all of you.